# Are there any side missions or unlockables in Mafia 2?

Tags: mafia-2

I am playing Mafia 2 and I reached now chapter 9. I am now wondering if is there anything else to find in the city outside of what proposed by plot. I mean additional missions, unlockable, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, not a lot.

Mafia II is about as linear as they come. It's not necessarily a bad thing, but it's an open world game, with no real openness. Other than what's part of the story, there are really only a few side quests that will net you a few achievements/trophies that you can win.

- In chapter 2, you can help a lady out with repairing her car.
- Throughout the city are a lot of wanted posters you can collect.
- Throughout the story and city, you can find 50 Playboy magazines.
- Depending on your system (xbox, ps3, pc), there are others for things like driving 50 miles, driving different cars, etc.

There are also 2 DLC packs that extend the story for some of the characters: Jimmy's Vendetta, and Joe's Adventures.